# How to install add-ons in MS Office (Wine)

Tags: wine, playonlinux, plugins, microsoft-office, add-on

I am forced to use MS Office 2010 through `Wine` in order to colaborate with my colleagues who all use MS Office. I would like to know if, and how I can install Plugins for Word in Wine. Specifically I need the `Mendeley Plugin` (citation software) and the `Grammarly Plugin` (grammar correction). A general solution that helps me to figure it out myself would be welcome as well.

I saw [this post](https://blog.jedox.com/installing-the-jedox-excel-addin-on-linux-ms-office-2010-32-bit/) detailing how to install the `Jedox` Plugin for Excel in Wine. So I think, that in theory, this should be also possible for other Plugins, however, information and tutorials are extremly sparse.

Please do not suggest me `LibreOffice` as an alternative. I am trying to use the `LibreOffice` workaround for several years now and I have constantly problems with the compatability. This is especially the case for using Mendeley citations which are not correctly imported and exported.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but *Mendeley Plugin* seems to [be not working on Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32149). You can test it yourself. WineAppdb does [not mention *Grammarly*](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=Grammarly), so you can try it yourself.

Comment: @N0rbert. Thanks for your suggestion. How can I test it myself? Is there a general way to install plugins and test if they work?