# Problem in installing MS word addons (e.g. Grammerly) using playonlinux

Tags: 20.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-word

I have installed the MS-word using Playonlinux on Ubuntu (20.04) and I am looking for some help to install the plugins viz. Grammarly, Mendeley, etc. I tried to manually install "Grammarly" but failed.

I understand there are certain prerequisites for any such installations. Is there a way to find those prerequisites?

There are also similar unresolved request e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026335/how-to-install-add-ons-in-ms-office-wine) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280984/how-to-link-mendeley-plugin-and-ms-word-in-playonlinux)

**EDIT1:**

As suggested by [NOrbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) I tried installing the grammerly as a component.
Earlier I was trying only step I and III only (see following). Due to error obtained  I found step II is required. Now I will be installing in following steps.

Step I: Change the OS type

1. Open PlayOnLinux and Select Configure and go to "Wine" tab.
2. Find and open "Configure wine" which open a new dialouge box.
3. Select Application tab and there is an option to change Windows version.
   It may require a restart/reboot of virtual drive.

Step II:  Installed the prerequisite (if any, e.g .net Framework for grammerly)

1. Open PlayOnLinux and select Configure and go to "Install component" tab.
2. Select and installed the desired component (e.g. .Net Framework ).

Step III: Install Grammerly (thanks to NOrbert for suggestion)

1. Open PlayOnLinux and select "Install a program"
2. Select "Install a Non listed program"
3. Select "Edit/update an existing program"
4. Choose program (e.g. MS word in this case)
5. Leave unchecked as already installed the component in previous step.
6. 32 bit installation
7. Browse the location and click next for installation.

The problem right now is in step II.
I do not know which version of .Net is required. Also I tried installing its "dotnet30" (hit and trial basis) but it failed.

Comment: Some parts of Word addons use VBA, which does not work on wine. See MathType [as example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043961/66509). Maybe searching on appdb.winehq.com may help.

Comment: Your suggestion helped partially. Now I am facing problem is a little bit different (updating question accordingly). Any help is appreciated.